# Bootstrap "Buttons addons" isn't working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, search

I am trying to make a search bar with the search button contained within the bar. I'm following this method: (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) and I typed in the code exactly as written, but my search button is still outside the search bar:

[image: searchbar]

Does anyone know why my result might be different from the one shown on the bootstrap website?

**This is my applicaton.rb:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `applicaton.rb` is supposed to be Ruby, but your snippet is HTML...

Answer (score 1):

You should include the bootstrap stylesheet and JS plugin. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Include bootstrap stylesheet -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to include normalize.css or any other reset css. Bootstrap already includes normalize.css.